# List auxiliary windows

Tags: javascript

With the function `window.open()` one can spawn auxiliary windows and tabs.

How can I get a list of the spawned auxiliary windows and tabs of the "parent" page in JavaScript?

***EDIT***: I'm looking for a way to do this *without* keeping track of the windows I create as they are created.

Comment: Windows opened via `window.open()` are *not* child windows of the opener window. They are not nested windows, but top-level windows. The correct term (according to [the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#auxiliary-browsing-context)) is "auxiliary windows".

Comment: @ŠimeVidas the whole "parent/child" semantic mess with windows and iframes always bothered me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this in javascript. You need to keep track of them yourself:

```
var windowArray = [];

// whenever you open a window...
var newWindow = window.open(...);
windowArray.push(newWindow);

// whenever you close a window...
if (opener && !opener.closed && opener.windowArray) {
    // search for your window in the array

    var matchingIndex = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < opener.windowArray.length; i++) {
        if (opener.windowArray[i] === window) {
            matchingIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if your window was found, remove it
    if (matchingIndex !== -1) {
       opener.windowArray.splice(matchingIndex, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `There is no way to do this in javascript.` - Do you have evidence/proof?

Comment: @Randomblue proof: no; "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence". if child windows are kept track of natively, i think the entire internet would love to know ;)

Comment: @Randomblue an interesting tangent if you're a fan of philosophy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_ignorance

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a built-in way to return child windows and tabs in js but you could create an array to keep track of them by creating an entry in the array every time you call window.open()

Answer (score 1):

I don't **think** it's possible to do that directly, though you could save the windows in an array:

```
var wins = [];
function openWindow(win){
   newWin = window.open(win);
   wins.push(newWin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var windowArray = [];
windowArray.push(window.open(yourWindow));
```

`windowArray` will store references to all the opened windows or tabs.